# Why the odd voting pattern?

Tags: discussion

[This question](https://christianity.stackexchange.com/q/30609/20) has a peculiar voting pattern:

Today

-2   15:24   downvoted  Why wasn't Noah's wife name revealed?

+2   1:22    undownvoted    Why wasn't Noah's wife name revealed?

Jul 06

+5   22:53   upvoted    Why wasn't Noah's wife name revealed?

-2   15:33   downvoted  Why wasn't Noah's wife name revealed?

+5   0:07    upvoted    Why wasn't Noah's wife name revealed?

+2   0:07    undownvoted    Why wasn't Noah's wife name revealed?

Jul 05

-2   23:53   downvoted  Why wasn't Noah's wife name revealed?

-2   23:28   downvoted  Why wasn't Noah's wife name revealed?

What can it be the why 'Why wasn't Noah's wife name revealed?' has got such a contorted vote pattern?

Answer (score 5):

- Someone downvoted, then undownvoted
- 2 upvotes, and a downvote and downvote reversal
- a downvote and a downvote reversal

This is a bit of a weird pattern, but, ultimately, the question is one that has no real answer in Christianity, and is a bit of an oddball..

It might help to remember that the guidelines for [asking a question](https://christianity.stackexchange.com/help/dont-ask):

> You should only ask practical, answerable questions based on actual problems that you face. Chatty, open-ended questions diminish the usefulness of our site and push other questions off the front page.

If this is a question about a problem you actually face, you need to make it much clearer, *why it is important that you know*. I don't know that this is the cause of the screwy voting, but when you ask questions that run afoul of this kind of guidance (and we do allow those, they just are discouraged), you run that risk.

Answer (score 3):

I'm not 100% sure but I think I was someone who downvoted and the undownvoted. If I did then it's because the scope was badly defined, and now is much better defined.